# How to do MASSIVE amount of calculations inside SQL Server efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do some calculations to simulate future metrics. I have a table of 200,000 customers and I need to calculate projected revenues for the next 160 months into the future.

That means that I am looking SQL Server doing in excess of 32 million calculations. and I need them to happen fast.

So far I've tried the naïve approach by cross joining the customer table to a future period table and doing calculations. The problem is that SQL Server takes all night and in fact doesn't finish these calculations.

I know this has to be possible, I just don't know how to do it SQL server.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide some [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and your query so that we can help you

Comment: Check the execution plan, it is likely that SQL Server is waiting for memory to perform the cross-join: this can be very high: 160*200000*(row/index length for tbl+the same for the period table). CROSS APPLY or looping in a TSQL WHILE loop may help. If you need more help, it would be good if you provide table structures, sample data, and index definitions. Try for one period first, how many seconds does it take?

Comment: Without seeing your table schema, indexes. sample data, the query and its execution plan, no one is likely able to help you.